# I have the package downgrade issues at angular 4

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I got the previously developed angular project from my company. I tried to start that after npm install. I got the following error. And I have here mentioned my package details. Please checkout and please gave me some instruction to solve this issues.

Error:

> ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module
>   E:/new-arog-V3.0/arogui-v.3.0/node_modules/angular-datatables/index.d.ts,
>   found version 4, expected 3, reso
>       lving symbol PagesModule in E:/new-arog-V3.0/arogui-v.3.0/src/app/arog/pages/pages.module.ts,
>   resolving symbol PagesModule in E:/new-arog-V3.0/arogui-v.3.0/src/
>       app/arog/pages/pages.module.ts
>           at syntaxError (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1729:34)
>           at simplifyInContext (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24979:23)
>           at StaticReflector.simplify (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24991:13)
>           at StaticReflector.annotations (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:24418:41)
>           at _getNgModuleMetadata (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:138:31)
>           at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:109:26)
>           at E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
>           at Array.reduce (native)
>           at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
>           at E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:129:27
>           at Array.reduce (native)
>           at _extractLazyRoutesFromStaticModule (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:128:10)
>           at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_impl.js:53:22)
>           at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtools_api.js:91:39)
>           at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:212:44)
>           at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (E:\new-arog-V3.0\arogui-v.3.0\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\plugin.js:448:24)

My  package.json file details:

```
 {

  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.4",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.4",
    "@ngui/auto-complete": "^0.16.0",
    "@types/c3": "^0.4.48",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.8",
    "@types/underscore": "^1.8.5",
    "angular-datatables": "^5.0.0",
    "angular-file-saver": "^1.1.3",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^2.1.3",
    "angular2-ui-switch": "^1.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "datatables.net": "^1.10.16",
    "datatables.net-dt": "^1.10.16",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "ng2-auto-complete": "^0.12.0",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.1.9",
    "ng2-date-picker": "^2.6.2",
    "ng2-datepicker-bootstrap": "^1.0.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-redux": "^5.1.2",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.3.1",
    "ng2-simple-autocomplete": "^0.6.0",
    "ng2-simple-dropdown": "^1.0.4",
    "ng2-toastr": "^4.1.2",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-beta.9",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-gallery": "^4.1.1",
    "primeng": "^4.2.1",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "tassign": "^1.0.0",
    "typings": "^2.1.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.4.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.4.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.4.2",       
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

I have downgrade the version. Still did not start the app.

Comment: remove `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and set the `angular-datatables` version to `4.4.1`, because version `5` is for angular5, then run `npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

why downgrade ? If the app was build in version 5 it's not a very good idea to downgrade...

try re/update your angular package and clean npm cache

Comment: After done your steps. Still I am getting the same error